# Struts2 web application getting unresponsive after few minute

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I am getting a problem with my struts2 application which i have develop. The problem is when application run it will get unresponsive after few minutes and i have to kill the process and again i have start tomcat on local server. I do not understand what is the issue. I have check the status of tomcat process on command prompt and found that the process is in `fin_wait_2`. I don't know why it is creating such issue. earlier it was working fine and i have only changed the hard coded datasource with JNDI.

**JNDI code is here:**

context.xml

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" maxActive="100" maxIdle="20" maxWait="10000" name="jdbc/testdb" password="FDmh5cUt7bY3K47u" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tests" username="root"/>
```

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
   <res-ref-name>jdbc/testdb</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

I have also get this datasource from context and set into servletcontext using servetcontextlistener.

DB_Listener.java

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
ds = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/testdb");
ServletContext context=sce.getServletContext();
context.setAttribute("ds", ds);
```

i have also make listener entry in web.xml file too.

```
<listener>
   <description>ServletContextListener</description>
   <listener-class>com.org.servlet.DB_Listener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here, I don't understand why application getting unresponsive. Everything working fine from login to datasource, but after few minute application get hanged or unresponsive.

Please friends help me what to do.

Comment: As, i have mentioned i have just change hard coded data source with jndi.

Comment: You did a lot, reinstall the server.

Comment: actually i am using netbeans 8.0 for development and for mysql i am using  xampp. is it a problem. As you have mention i have done lot of server reinstall, then how to solve this issue.